# Can you open this lock?

Tags: visual

This is part of my "guess the 4-digit number" series. If you like, you can see the other puzzles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32235/what-number-is-hidden-in-this-card), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33466/what-number-is-hidden-in-this-crime-scene), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33534/what-number-is-hidden-in-this-gallery) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42867/what-number-is-hidden-in-this-map).

On the right you can see a lock, which keeps the door of my hut closed. On the left you can see a strange object, which I keep next to my hut. Can you guess the combination of the lock?

[image]

Comment: Does it have something to do with the sum of the sections of each color, or a hidden number of each color?

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush I would say it is simpler. If you find the answer, you will know it is correct.

Comment: Was just passing by and saw this. At first I tried to solve it, but then looked for an answer. I can't write comments, so sorry, but I couldn't keep silence. And I don't get it. How did you get the digits? The first digit is 0. Everyone here agrees on that. Suppose the number of separate flat surfaces is a key to the lock. There are 5 blue surfaces. Let's slide the slider 5 times. And we will get 5, not 0. Ok. Maybe it's the straight flat surfaces. And there are 7 of them. Nope. That won't help. Suppose, you put the figure looking at one color. I still don't get it. Sorry for my stupidity, but

Comment: +1 for very appealing visuals. How did you make them?

Comment: You might want to "group" your series puzzles slightly better. Instead of relinking them all (and needing to edit the links), you can provide a clearly searchable starter-line and then provide a link to a search for exactly this "identification". Like I did for [my own series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9835/what-does-this-modern-art-picture-represent).

Comment: @BmyGuest that's a good idea, thanks. Will do that later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it

> 0251?

Because

> If you were to view the figure so the the color on top is the color of the slider (orange is on the bottom) you see a 0 for blue, 2 for green, 5 for orange, and 1 for red. You can view a 3d model of the figure [here](http://a360.co/2pHKNVV).

Comment: Almost there. The color at the back of the piece is yellow, not orange.

Comment: Is it right now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct!

Comment: Very resourceful way to get 4 different digits, @Artur Kirkoryan

Comment: This was my first thought except for the red number, which would appear to be just a big ol' square?

Comment: @moopet : Except that the "square" would actually be a rectangle, as the length and height are not the same, and a san-serif 1 at its base is just a rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is:

> 0251

because

> if viewing the planes, you would see each number, with the orange being underneath, so opposite the 2, which is 5.

Comment: That's correct, but qwewqa beat you with few seconds to it:)

Comment: Leave it to me to be slow on the save... Nice puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Are

> 0521, 0551 and 0221

not also possible answers?

> Or are there some hidden instructions i do not see, which specify where the bottom of the different sides is supposed to be?

Comment: How can you look at individual colors from multiple sides? I can see, every color can be seen from only one side.

Comment: You can rotate what you see 180° clockwise, since you (or at least i) do not know what the correct position is, there are multiple possibilities. For example if i came from the left side, the second row solution would be the smaller number, but coming from the ride side it would look like the larger number.

Comment: @IIOIOOO Rotating the digit 2 or 5 by 180 degrees keeps it the same. They are mirror images of each other, and you can only get to see the mirror image if you look at the shape from the opposite side, which will have a different colour.

Comment: *insert facepalm* indeed, you are right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> 2201

Because

> 5 Blue and 5 Green and 0 orange and 4 red...

Comment: Welcome to PSE! First of all, it's customary to put your answers in spoiler tags so as not to ruin the surprise. Secondly, this question has already been correctly answered. Thirdly, you might want to elaborate on your reasoning. I had to check the image a couple of times before realizing what you meant but I still don't understand how it connects to your actual answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy / sorry my first puzzle and my first day off in 3 years so im a noob to having fun...i promise my next puzzle will be spectacularly answered...!

Comment: @James You can still edit your answer to indicate the reasoning behind it. It might help someone in the future, and will in general be a good practice to have.

Comment: How do you get 2s from 5s and 1 from 4 if 0=0?